# Secondary Axis Range from 0 to None in Update Layout Not Working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a data of total sales and total invoices (rows) per Year. I want to plot them in a bar and line chart. I successfully made the chart with plotly.

However I am having problem in adjusting the secondary yaxis to start from 0 and not automatically set by plotly.

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=smy[smy['variable'] == 'Weekly_Sales_sum']['Year'],
    y=smy[smy['variable'] == 'Weekly_Sales_sum']['value'],
    name='Weekly Sales Sum'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=smy[smy['variable'] == 'Weekly_Sales_size']['Year'],
    y=smy[smy['variable'] == 'Weekly_Sales_size']['value'],
    name='Weekly Sales Size',
    yaxis='y2'
))

fig.update_layout(title='Bar and Line Chart for Weekly Sales Sum and Size',
                  yaxis=dict(title='Weekly Sales Sum'),
                  yaxis2=dict(title='Weekly Sales Size', overlaying='y', side='right', range=[0, None]))

pyo.iplot(fig)
```

I have set the `fig`'s `update_layout` to start the secondary axis to start from 0 using `range=[0, None]` but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I believe your secondary y-axis is starting from 0, there just isn't a tick for it on the axis. The 2,012.5 you circled is from your x-axis. If you mean that you would like the 0 tick displayed on the secondary y-axis you could use custom ticks with `tickvals` and `ticktext` in your `update_layout` call.

Comment: The secondary yaxis (the right side) clearly doesn't start from 0. The primary yaxis one does (the left side). At the bottom of it shows 0 (above 2,009.5).  That is what I am trying to do to the secondary yaxis

Comment: @user2552108 Running your code, the range clearly starts from 0 on _both_ yaxis and yaxis2 - tested on plolty.py 5.17.0. I revised my answer to add clarifications though.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `range=[0, None]` to `yaxis2` actually works (the range clearly starts from 0 on both yaxis and yaxis2 - tested on plolty.py 5.17.0). However, because of the layout [`autosize`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-autosize) and the axes [`autorange`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-autorange) (both `True` by default), resizing the window or resetting the axes will reset that range and make it fit the input data, which you apparently don't want.

To prevent this, set **`rangemode='tozero'`** :

> [`rangemode`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-rangemode) - If `"normal"`, the range is computed in relation to the extrema of the input data. If `"tozero"`, the range extends to 0, regardless of the input data.

---

Also, as pointed out by @kevin41, the `2009.5` and `2012.5` are on the x axis, there are added because years in `x` are treated as numbers, so you would need to set the xaxis [`dtick`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-dtick) accordingly to prevent showing intermediate values :

```py
fig.update_layout(xaxis_dtick=1)
```

In fact you probably want them (the years in x) to be treated as date by setting the x axis [`type`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-type) accordingly, but you would have `Jul 2012` instead of `2012.5` so you would still need to specify `dtick` to show only years :

```py
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(type='date', dtick='M12'))
```

You could also make them treated as category, in which case no need to set `dtick` :

```py
fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')
```

---

Full example :

```py
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x=[2010, 2011, 2012],
    y=[2.30e9, 2.45e9, 2e9],
    name='Weekly Sales Sum'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[2010, 2011, 2012],
    y=[1.42e6, 1.53e6, 1.27e6],
    name='Weekly Sales Size',
    yaxis='y2'
))

fig.update_layout(
    title='Bar and Line Chart for Weekly Sales Sum and Size',
    xaxis=dict(type='date', dtick='M12'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Weekly Sales Sum'),
    yaxis2=dict(rangemode='tozero', title='Weekly Sales Size', overlaying='y', side='right')
)

pyo.iplot(fig)
```

[image]